# val x: Int => Int = { y => y } What does this scala code mean?

Tags: scala

`val x: Int=> Int = { y => y }` // ① This is correct

`( x1: Int) => Int = { y => y}`  // ② This is wrong

I understand a simple scala function like this ：`x:Int =>  x`

or this ：`val f =(x: Int) => x`

but how to explain the role of  "x" in the sentence ①

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `val x: Int=> Int = { y => y }`, `Int=> Int` is used to *define the return type* of `x` *immutable variable which takes Int as input and returns an Int value*.

`(x1: Int) => Int = { y => y}` is wrong because a function cannot be assigned to another function as `(x1: Int) => Int` is a function and `{ y => y}` is another function

`val f =(x: Int) => x` is correct as you are assigning `(x: Int) => x` function which takes an integer value as input and returns as it is and is assigned to a immutable variable f.

**Defining x in one line** would be *x is a immutable input variable passed in to a function where manipulation on x is performed*.

Comment: thank  you, I got it . the variable "x"  reference a function of ( Int => Int ) 。I also could write it like this val x: (Int=> Int) = { y => y }

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
val x: Int=> Int = { y => y }
```

Above can be written as:
 `val x: Int=> Int = { identity}`

x is a function which receives an integer and returns the same integer.

```
scala> x(5)
res4: Int = 5
```